# Java Table of dynamic Objects

Tags: java, object, dynamic

I am making a Java program but don't really know how to start. The assignment is:

I have to create a table with c - columns and r-  rows. This parameter are the first one I read(can both be up to 100). So this part is clear. Then, regarding the number of columns (using for statement I guess) I have to set their types. For example if I enter c = 5 and r=5, I will have a table 5x5. Then I need to read 5(c) inputs where 1 presents Integer, 2 presents String and 3 presents Boolean.

So if I then enter: 1 1 2 2 3, this means that I will have first 2 types that are integer, next 2 as String and the last one Boolean. I guess I would need to create an Object like this, but not sure how to create it "dynamically" - after I get this types.

After that I will read the 5(r) object that each have that 5 parameters. The next step I would then try on my own, just not sure how to implements such input - the create of the object with types I set.

This is what I got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tables {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        int [] types = new int [c];


        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
            types[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        //have types but how to create an object now?

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but in your case, I would use the simplest and most straightforward method, which is a `switch` statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c; c++) {

        Object value = null;

        switch (types[j]) {
            case 1:
                value = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            case 2:
                value = sc.next();
                break;
            case 3:
                value = sc.nextBoolean();
                break;
        }

        // Do something with 'value' here.
    }
}
```